# ¿ Puedo realizar esto en el MER?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelos

queria consultar si es posible realizar esto en el modelo entidad relacion:
[image: Una relacion compartida]

Ya que segun el enunciado los proyectos de investigación pueden ser de un tipo (publicaciones, libros, patentes), y no veo que se pueda utilizar la herencia del modelo entidad relacion extendido, ya que ahí especifica que "De los proyectos de investigación se pueden OBTENER publicaciones, libros, patentes".

Así que quisiera saber si esto se puede realizar.

Igualmente adjunto un poco del enunciado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La respuesta a esto será basada en opiniones, lo cual no va acorde a este sitio, por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Mas alla de que esto es basado en opiniones, y el unico que tiene la respuesta correcta es tu profesor (porque nosotros opinamos de afuera), la pregunta que te haria es, porque no?

Comment: Esto es una opinión: Usa un código que este referenciado en las 3. Este podría ser cualquier identificador único